# elasticsearch sort aggregation on categorical value

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation, categorical-data

In elasticsearch, I can aggregate and sort the aggregation on a second aggregation's **numeric** field.

e.g.

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "a1": {
      "terms": { 
        "field": "FIELD1",
        "size":0,
        "order": {"a2": "desc"}  
      },
      "aggs":{
        "a2":{
          "sum":{
            "field":"FIELD2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I want to sort the aggregation on a **categorical** field value. ie. let's say the value of FIELD2 was one of ("a", "b", "c") -- I want to sort a1 first by all documents's with FIELD2: "a", then FIELD2: "b", then FIELD2: "c".

In my case, every FIELD1 has a *unique* FIELD2. So I really just want a way to sort the a1 results by FIELD2.

Comment: Did you try doing it the same way as above query. ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you want but I tried following. 
I created index with mapping

```
PUT your_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type":   "string"
        },
        "fruit" : {"type" : "string", "index": "not_analyzed"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I indexed few documents like this

```
PUT your_index/your_type/1
{
  "name" : "federer",
  "fruit" : "orange"
}
```

Then I sorted all players with fruits with following aggregation

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "a1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "a2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "fruit",
            "order": {
              "_term": "asc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result I got is

```
"aggregations": {
      "a1": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "federer",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "a2": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "green apple",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "orange",
                        "doc_count": 2
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "messi",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "a2": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "apple",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "banana",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "nadal",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "a2": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "blueberry",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "watermelon",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "ronaldo",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "a2": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "banana",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "watermelon",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Make sure your **FIELD2** is `not_analyzed` or you will get unexpected results.

Does this help?

Comment: what he is trying to achieve is sorting the first aggregation based on the result of second aggregation(inner one). The twist here is the second aggregation is terms on character and the bucket result is of type string value and not  integer value.

Comment: If a inner aggregation is a mutli valued bucket, then it is not possible to sort the parent agg on child agg.

Comment: yes, @piyushGoyal is correct. In my case, the inner aggregation is never a multi valued bucket though, so I should be able to somehow sort agg1 values by agg2 values.

Comment: Right now elasticsearch API does not provide you this functionality. I tried tweaking and see if something works. It only provides sorting on single bucket aggs and that too numeric..! :(

Comment: even I tried some different queries and did not succeed. sorry could not help :(

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that works. You must first aggregate on FIELD2, **then** on FIELD1.

```
    {
      "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "a2": {
          "terms": {
            "size": 0,
            "field": "FIELD2",
            "order": {
              "_term": "asc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "a1": {
              "terms": {
                "size": 0,
                "field": "FIELD1",
                "order": {
                  "_term": "asc"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It is kind of opposite for what you asked in your question, isn't it?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 my objective was to sort the FIELD1 aggregation by FIELD2. By performing it this way, FIELD1 is sorted (although in a nested way) by FIELD2.